# ASP.NET Checkbox not being checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I will try to explain it the best I can, cause this problem is maybe the rarest I've found.

I've a control that extends the functionality of asp.net GridView. Inside it, I've the following two columns:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc2" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

As you can see, both ItemTemplates are identical. I don't reference them on any part of the solution but in the code behind on row_dataBound event. Inside this method, I do the following for both text boxes:

```
chk = e.Row.FindControl("chkEnviadoGesDoc") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
    {
        chk.Enabled = false;
        chk.Checked = (rowData["REI_ENVIO_GESDOC"].ToString().Contains("S"));
    }

    chk = e.Row.FindControl("chkEnviadoGesDoc2") as CheckBox;
    if (chk != null)
    {
        chk.Enabled = false;
        chk.Checked = (rowData["REI_ENVIO_GESDOC"].ToString().Contains("S"));

    }
```

This is the result I get on the web:

[image]

Senseless. If I inspect the code, even if the checkboxes are not marked, they've the property "checked = checked". If, for instance, I add a column before the first ItemTemplate:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YouText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Prueba
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc2" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Now the result is:

[image]

If I inspect the HTML, here's the HTML for the checked chebox and the uncheked one:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$SeguimientoInterfaces$GrdInterfaces$ctl08$chkEnviadoGesDoc" disabled="disabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_SeguimientoInterfaces_GrdInterfaces_chkEnviadoGesDoc_6" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TabContainer1$TabPanel1$SeguimientoInterfaces$GrdInterfaces$ctl08$chkEnviadoGesDoc2" disabled="disabled" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_SeguimientoInterfaces_GrdInterfaces_chkEnviadoGesDoc2_6" type="checkbox" checked="checked">
```

If I manually remove the check and check again, the check works:

```
jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_SeguimientoInterfaces_GrdInterfaces_chkEnviadoGesDoc2_6").attr("checked", "")
jQuery("#ContentPlaceHolder1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_SeguimientoInterfaces_GrdInterfaces_chkEnviadoGesDoc2_6").attr("checked", "checked")
```

As you can see, none of the checkboxes are checked, even they've the property set in html.

If I add this "TestColumn" in middle of my both identical columns, then they work correctly:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="YouText">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Prueba
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Enviado GesDoc2">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEnviadoGesDoc2" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
</asp:TemplateField>
```

[image]

I don't get any exception while running the code. Html is the same for the case when the checkbox is marked with the tick and when it's not. I don't have any idea what can cause this behavior. If you have any though, please share it and help me.

Thank you

Comment: Tested your code. It works fine. Both checkboxes are checked even without an extra column in between. Did you try a different browser and/or are the checkboxes styled by a bootstrapper and/or css and javscript? Maybe there lies the problem.

Comment: @VDWWD It works fine for me also if I switch to normal GridView, but im using a custom GridView that extends GridView functionality

Comment: Then the error is somewhere in the extension. But nobody can test that since it is not in your question.

Comment: @VDWWD I cannot post the full extension code. Im asking if someone could guess what could go wrong to make this behavior, I know it's complicated, but I've to try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question was solved myself. There was a function in javascript setting checked property manually to false (instead using attr function), that's why my checkbox was being displayed without check but still had the "checked" attr in html.

The internal coding of this function caused the stranged behaviors when adding a text column in between the checkboxes columns or before them.